# Collapside opening upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding and I want to have like these panels on the bottom of the page that when pressed it opens some menu with buttons and stuff and I think the best choice would be collapside. But after reading the W3schools tutorial I didn´t find any reference on how to make them open pointing up. I hope it just don´t move the whole page and just opens a clickable window. If not I would like to know which other thing to use for that. Here is the code from W3schools

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");
var content = this.nextElementSibling;
if (content.style.maxHeight){
  content.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
} 
});
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
background-color: #777;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
content: '\002B';
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
content: "\2212";
}

.content {
padding: 0 18px;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
<p>upper one (only one is enought).</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
<p>1.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
<p>2.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
<p>3.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your `content` variable to `previousElementSibling` to get the element before.

```
var content = this.previousElementSibling;
```

Then, swap the order of the collapse button and content like so:

```
<div class="content">
      <p>upper one (only one is enought).</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gf72yw8q/

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to do something with dropdown now but this seems better. But can you actually have collapse in collapse? And when clicked can it open od side of the collapside not on the upper side? (sorry I don´t know how all this stuff is called, just like positioning it on the right for example).

Comment: @Holsp sure thing! If it was helpful please consider marking the question as answered. 
You can collapse in collapse you would just add the same <div> <button> within the content of another.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they open downwards is because the html structure and css is indicating for it to be that way, for example:

```
<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
<p>upper one (only one is enought).</p>
</div>
```

The `<p>` with the text "upper one" (in this case your content) appears after open `<button>`.
If you want it to open upwards, the content would thus need to appear (in the html) before the button (to avoid using additional css styles to reproduce the intended effect).

for example:

```
<ul class="magic-content">
<li>an example list item</li>
<li>another example item</li>
</ul>
<a class="magic-button" href="#">my magic button</a>
```

to make this work, you would then need something like this inside your js file. For the purpose of this example, I am using jquery:

```
//FILTERS RESET
$('.magic-button').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault;
    $('.magic-content').toggleClass('on');
});
```

And your css would need to have something such as:

```
.magic-content {display:none;}
.magic-content.on {display:block;}
```

So that the toggling of the class 'on' is what triggers the showing/hiding of the content.

ALTERNATIVELY, the example you are referring to can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class_crossbrowser

And all you need to do in their example to reverse the order is change the order of the html elements:

```
<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

The button after the content. I hope this helps.
G